# Use of "in" when setting javascript variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax

I've recently been given this piece of javascript (as part of a jQuery function)...

```
var h = "innerHeight" in window ? window.innerHeight : document.documentElement.offsetHeight;
var w = "innerWidth" in window ? window.innerWidth : document.documentElement.offsetWidth;
```

I've never seen `"innerHeight" in` used before, and I cannot find any explanation of what it is for, or why it's used.  (Doing a Google search for the word `in` isn't exactly helpful.)

Is it jQuery syntax?

Comment: I've put "javascript in" in google and it provided a bunch of relevant results. Haven't you heard of http://google.com?

Comment: @KarlenKishmiryan ,plese , OP gets nervous when he sees tag POSSIBLE DUPLICATE OF ............. .He didnt do any crime :(

Comment: @Pratik Joshi: they did actually. They didn't bother trying to solve it themselves.

Comment: @Amit Joki: excuse me? No it's not. Why are you asking?

Comment: @zerkms, that was a joke ;)

Comment: @zerkms, let me see - erm, yes, I've heard of Google - I even mention it in my question.  However, I stupidly didn't search for `javascript in`... I searched for `javascript var in` which gave me masses of results about `for(var x in y)`

Comment: @zerkms ,Yes you are excused ,You have given ExCuSe.

Comment: @zerkms, in reponse to `They didn't bother trying to solve it themselves`... are you always so objectionable?  Yes, I did try and solve it for myself - I searched Google (which you obviously missed me mentioning in my question) but obviously badly.  There is no need to be obnoxious about it - or is that a privilege of having nearly 100k rep??

Comment: @freefaller: the thing is - if a person asks about trivial syntax - in 99.99% it means they didn't even try to google. My apologies to you and I honestly cannot understand how it's possible to not google about it in a minute. It seriously surprises me.

Comment: @zerkms - I'm actually known by my colleagues for being really bad at coming up with good Google search terms, this appear to be no different.  My mistake was thinking it was part of the `var` declaration, rather than an operator in it's own right. (Apology accepted)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, [the `in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) is core JavaScript.

It resolves as `true` if the object on the right hand side has a property with a name that matches the string on the left hand side.

See [a simple example](http://jsfiddle.net/k79nD/):

```
var foo = {
    a: 1,
    b: undefined
}

var o = document.getElementById('output');

o.innerHTML = ("a" in foo) + "<br>" + 
    ("b" in foo) + "<br>" + 
    ("c" in foo) + "<br>";
```

Comment: Thanks Quentin - as zerkms "helpfully" points out in their comment under the question, I didn't search for the correct thing - your explanation is excellent

Answer (score 2):

This is pure JS.

This is similar to `object.property` with a little difference.

`object.property` will fail in cases property is not set  and also in cases it has been set to some false value, e.g. undefined, null, 0 etc

`property in object` is slightly better because it doesn't looks for its value.

Answer (score 2):

**Check if a object's property exists.**

`in` is used to check if an object contains a specific property , this is rappresented by a string.

```
var obj={a:1,b:2}

// in
console.log('a' in obj); // true
console.log('c' in obj); // false
```

Said that.. there is a faster/shorter way to do that.

```
// this does not work if the property's value is 0,null,undefined,false...
console.log(!!obj.a); // true  
console.log(!!obj.c); // false
```

**demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/cLDEd/

in your case a better solution would be:

```
var H=window.innerHeight?window.innerHeight:document.documentElement.offsetHeight
```

or even better :

```
var H=window.innerHeight||document.documentElement.offsetHeight
```

Theoretically `window.innerHeight` could be `0` , so at that point it would try to get the `document.documentElement.offsetHeight` whitch returns `undefined` and you should add another or `||0` to return `0` and not `undefined`. But that does not happen ;).

Putting `window.innerHeight` in front of `document.documentElement.offsetHeight` accelerates the check as `window.innerHeight` is standard, so there is a higher chance that it's the correct choice.

Answer (score 0):

You can see it as if `innerHeight <inside> window` then `window`....

Comment: What `inside` term means?